# Interior of closed ball

Tags: analysis, convex-analysis

I'm an absolute beginner in Convex analysis.
I'm wondering how the following statement is true.
I just got this from a lecture notes  and unfortunately no proof is provided.

"The interior of the closed ball $\{x :\| x−a \|_2 \leq r\}$ is the open ball $\{x :\| x−a \|_2< r\}$ " 
Note: $\| \cdot \|_2$ mean $L_2$ norm.

Comment: Yes, this is true. It is also very very simple to prove.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets denote $A=\{ x: \| x-a \|_2 \leq r\}$ and $B=\{ x: \| x-a \|_2 < r\}$, then if $x \in B$, put $R=r-\|x-a\|_2$, and then
$$
B_R(x) = \{ y : \| y-x\|_2< R \} \subset A
$$
This gives that any point in $B$ is an interior point of $A$.

Now if you take any $x \not\in B$ ($x$ is such that $\|x-a\|_2\geq r$) then for any $R>0$, $B_R(x)$ is not totally contained in $A$ (for example if $\| y-a\|_2>r$ then for all $R>0$, $y \in B_R(y)$ but $y \not \in A$). This gives that all the interiors points of $A$ are the ones in $B$, which of course means that $B$ is the interior of $A$.

Comment: Thank you, Mr.Alonso Delfín:-)

Comment: You are welcome ! Glad to help